# How can I make JQuery autocomplete go to the user's page like Facebook in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

This is my search form, all results displayed are users on my site using JQuery autocomplete. When I select the searched user's name, I simple want the form to go to the go to the profile page of the user on Submit or when I click on the selected user's name and bring up their profile. Much like Facebook.

```
<form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" name="term" class="form-control inputsearch"  placeholder="Search..." />
         <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default searchbar" type="submit">
              <i class="fa fa-search searchnow"></i>
             </button>
         </span>
      </div>
</form>
```

This is the JQuery autocomplete function

```
$(function() {
$("input[name=term]").autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
});
```

These are my routes for the autocomplete and getting the user's profile

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{name}', [
'uses' => 'UserController@getProfile',
'as' => 'profile.index',
]);


Route::get('/autocomplete',[
'uses'=>'UserController@autocomplete',
'as'=>'autocomplete'
]);
```

And finally, this is my controller:

```
 public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        return  User::select(['id', 'name as value'])->where(function($query) use ($request) {
            if ( ($term = $request->get("term")) )
            {
                $keywords = '%' . $term . '%';
                $query->orWhere("name", 'LIKE', $keywords);
                $query->orWhere("email", 'LIKE', $keywords);
            }
        })
            ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
    }
}

public function getProfile($name)
{
    $user = User::where('name', $name)->first();
    if(!$user){
        abort(404);
    }
    $posts = Post::where("user_id", "=", $user->id)->latest()->paginate(3);
    $photos = Photo::paginate(6);
    return view('profile.index',compact('user','posts', 'photos'));

}
```

What can I modify to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, the code doesnt work but it gives you an idea

```
$(function() {
$("input[name=term]").autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var userid = ui.item.value; // just try to get user id here 
     window.location.href = "yourapp/user/"+userid ;
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This is working for when I click the result! Thank you. However, the search form no longer autocompletes once I'm visiting another user's page, only works when I'm on the authorized user's profile. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: what does its ay when u click another user? i dont get it! can you add details as an update